# The output 1.0e+07 * -3.5659 0.00001 in Matlab

Tags: matlab

If my output is

```
  xs =
 1.0e+07 *
  -3.5659
   0.00001
```

in Matlab. I am confused about the xs=[ -3.5659, 0.00001]*10^7 or xs=[ -3.5659*10^7, 0.00001]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiplier applies to the whole array. You can verify this by examining each of the values independently: type `xs(1)` and `xs(2)`.

This is rather inconvenient when there's many orders of magnitude difference between array elements, as the smaller elements will be shown as 0.0. But on the other hand makes it easier to compare the values in the array, and the display is more compact as well.